# Incrementing values with react

Tags: react-hooks

Using react, I called {useState} to have a bank account that has two objects (money & cost). I am trying to increment the value of money every time I click on the button tag. The issue I am having is that the value will only increment one time, and after I click more than once, then I get a TypeError: Cannot create property 'money' on number '1'. So it's not allowing me to click more than once. Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    let [bank, setBank] = useState({
        money: 1,
        cost: 0
    });

    const bake = (event) => {
        setBank(bank.money++)
        // alert('You are using the no bake pudding to make $1')
        console.log(bank.money);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h1>React Bakery</h1>
            <button onClick={bake}>Bake!</button>
            <h3>Account Balance = ${bank.money}</h3>
        </>
    );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

`setBank` overwrites the entire object, be sure to update only the key you care about:

```js
const bake = (event) => {
    setBank((b) => ({ money: b.money + 1, ...b }));
};
```